# Can I extract values from another dataframe based on presence of all values from list[str] column in another list[str] column without using apply?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have two dataframes like below:

```py
import polars as pl

df1 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [["a", "b", "c"], ["b", "c", "d"], ["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["d", "e", "f"]],
    }
)

df2 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [["a", "b"], ["b", "c"], ["c", "d"], ["b", "c", "d"]],
        "col2": ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    }
)
```

I want to lookup values from df1 in df2, selecting all of the df2.col2 values for rows where all the values in the df2.col1 list are present in the df1.col1 list.
Similar to https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/4670, but I don't think an explode/join/groupby will work due to memory constraints (the dfs I am working with are on the order of 100M rows).

Is there a way to do this in a fully lazy way without apply? (I'm using Polars v0.18.4)

I have an eager pipeline that works:

```py
output = (
    df1
    .with_columns(
        col2 = pl.col("col1").apply(
            lambda x: df2
                      .filter(pl.col("col1").list.eval(pl.element().is_in(x)).list.min())
                      .select(pl.col("col2").flatten())
                      .get_column("col2")
                      .to_list(),
            return_dtype=pl.List(pl.Utf8)
            )
    )
)
```

And a partial eager/lazy pipeline (note that df2 is not lazy, since `get_column` is not available for LazyFrames):

```py
output = (
    df1
    .lazy()
    .with_columns(
        col2 = pl.col("col1").apply(
            lambda x: df2
                      .filter(pl.col("col1").list.eval(pl.element().is_in(x)).list.min())
                      .select(pl.col("col2").flatten())
                      .get_column("col2")
                      .to_list(),
            return_dtype=pl.List(pl.Utf8)
            ),
    )
    .collect()
)
```

But my attempt at a fully lazy pipeline without apply fails due to `named columns are not allowed in arr.eval`.
Actually I'm not convinced it would work anyway, since the column in `.then()` likely isn't combined independently for df1 rows.

```py
output = (
    df1
    .lazy()
    .with_context(
        df2
        .lazy()
        .select(pl.all().suffix("_2"))
        )
    .with_columns(
        col2 =
            pl.when(
                pl.col("col1_2").list.eval(pl.element().is_in(pl.col("col1"))).list.min()
            ).then(
                pl.col("col2_2").flatten()
            ),
    )
    .collect()
)
# exceptions.ComputeError: named columns are not allowed in `arr.eval`; consider using `element` or `col("")`
```

Comment: If you're going to go with the lazy API, why not use an explode/join/groupby approach? Memory is less of a concern if you use the lazy API because the dataset will be paged on disk. I also imagine that exploding into a flat table for lazy operations will allow for more query optimization than using higher-level types like Lists.

Comment: Do I have to use something like sink_parquet for that to be true? What if I just `collect(streaming=True)` at the end, assuming the dataframe has been filtered down by then? I have had issues with memory usage spiking even in a streaming lazy context (e.g. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9698).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you confirmed the `explode/join/groupby` approach does not work?

```
with pl.StringCache():
    df1 = pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "col1": [["a", "b", "c"], ["b", "c", "d"], ["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["d", "e", "f"]],
        }
    ).lazy()
    
    df2 = pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "col1": [["a", "b"], ["b", "c"], ["c", "d"], ["b", "c", "d"]],
            "col2": ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
        }
    ).lazy()
    
    col1 = pl.col('col1').cast(pl.List(pl.Categorical)).to_physical().list.sort()
    
    a = df1.select(col1).with_row_count()
    b = df2.select(col1, 'col2').with_row_count()

    c = (
       a.explode('col1').join(b.explode('col1'), on='col1')
        .groupby('row_nr', 'row_nr_right')
        .agg('col1')
    )

    d = c.join(b, left_on='row_nr_right', right_on='row_nr')

    e = d.filter(pl.col('col1').hash() == pl.col('col1_right').hash())

    f = e.groupby('row_nr').agg('col2')

    f.collect().with_columns(str = '[' + pl.col('col2').list.join(', ') + ']')
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌────────┬───────────────────┬──────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ col2              ┆ str          │
│ ---    ┆ ---               ┆ ---          │
│ u32    ┆ list[str]         ┆ str          │
╞════════╪═══════════════════╪══════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ ["1", "2"]        ┆ [1, 2]       │
│ 1      ┆ ["3", "4", "2"]   ┆ [3, 4, 2]    │
│ 2      ┆ ["4", "2", … "1"] ┆ [4, 2, 3, 1] │
└────────┴───────────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will give that a go and get back to you.